# How can I total a Column when there is an #N/A or blank?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I want to be able to total an entire column. I want excel to give me the total sum of all numbers in the column and ignore the blanks and the #N/A.

How would I complete this?

Answer (score 0):

The regular Sum function ignores text and blank cells.
For example, given the following column:

```
1    Numbers
2    5
3    5
4    5
5    5
6    Text
7    
8    5
```

The formula: `=Sum(A2:A8)` would produce "25". If it is necessary to sum the entire column, you would need to make sure the formula is not in column A, and change it to =Sum(A:A).

Comment: It sounds like you should use the SUMIF function and explicitly exclude #N/A cells, as in:
SUMIF(B1:B8,"<>#N/A")
Works in my test.